# Button Does Not Update PHP SQL Server Table

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have this code and I want to make the BIT column Color 1 by pressing the check button and I really can't handle the php. I need help, please!

There is the table and how I access each data from the SQL server, it shows fine but the button is not doing anything when I'm trying to _POST in php. I have been looking for an answer but I couldn't find anything.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nr Expediente</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
      <th scope="col">Responsable</th>
      <th scope="col">Proveedor</th>
      <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
      <th scope="col">Hora</th>
      <th scope="col">Check</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

<?php

          $query="SELECT dbo.Transportes.IdExpediente, dbo.Operaciones.IdTransporte, dbo.Operaciones.Id, dbo.Operaciones.Color, dbo.Operaciones.CreadoPor, dbo.Expedientes.Numero, dbo.Expedientes.ProveedorNombre, dbo.Operaciones.Fecha, dbo.Operaciones.Tipo, dbo.Operaciones.Hora, dbo.Operaciones.Instrucciones FROM dbo.Expedientes 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Transportes ON dbo.Expedientes.Id = dbo.Transportes.IdExpediente INNER JOIN dbo.Operaciones ON dbo.Operaciones.IdTransporte = dbo.Transportes.Id 
      WHERE convert(date, convert(varchar(30), dbo.Operaciones.Fecha), 101) = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) AND dbo.Operaciones.Tipo = 0 ORDER BY dbo.Operaciones.Id DESC";
      $res=sqlsrv_query($con,$query);

      while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)){
        ?>
        <tr <?php if ($row['Color'] == 1) {
            echo 'class="table-success"';
        } else { echo 'class="table-warning"';} ?> ><td><a href=""><?php echo $row['Numero']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Fecha']->format('d/m/Y'); ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($row['Tipo'] == 1) {
            echo "Descarga";
        } else { echo "Carga";} ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['CreadoPor']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ProveedorNombre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Instrucciones']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Hora']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <form method="post">
        <div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" name="Checking" class="btn btn-success">Check</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' .$row['Id']. '"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="color" value="1"/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">In progress</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save for later</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <button type="butoon" name="Unchecking">Uncheck</a>
  </div>
</div> </form></td></tr>
    <?php
      }

      ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

    <?php if(isset($_POST['Checking'])){
         $sql = "UPDATE dbo.Operaciones SET
                Color = '1'
                WHERE Id = {_POST['id']} ";
    
        $result = sqlsrv_query($con,$sql) or die(sqlsrv_errors());

        } 
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise how dangerous could be.

Comment: @AndreiNedelcu, what do you expect to happen when you use `... WHERE Id = {_POST['id']}`? You need to use `... WHERE Id = {$_POST['id']}` instead. Also, always use parameters in your statements, something like: `$sql = "UPDATE dbo.Operaciones SET Color = '1' WHERE Id = ? "; $prm = array($_POST['id']); $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql, $prm) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));`.

Answer (score 0):

change **type="button"** to **type="submit"**

and
change

```
           $sql = "UPDATE dbo.Operaciones SET
            Color = '1'
            WHERE Id = ".$_POST['id'] ;
```

Comment: I did the changes and it's still not working. :( Thanks for your input though!

Comment: what error it is giving?. can you please tell me ?

Comment: Where I have sqlsrv_errors it shows me Array, I'm trying to find if the connection array is the problem. But then why does it list the table with that connection?

Comment: please copy paste the error here

Comment: It's literally just that, it shows Array where that code is.

Comment: @AndreiNedelcu, `... die(sqlsrv_errors())` will print `Array()`, what you want is `...die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));`